# xsl sort doesn't work on xsl:apply-templates

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to sort xml file about planets data by decreasing diameter with this instruction:

```
<xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
```

but xsl:sort doesn't work :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="//planete">
 <html lang="fr">
  <head>
   <title>Les planètes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template> 
 
  <xsl:template match="systeme_solaire/planete" >
   <xsl:if test="nom!='Terre'">
   <xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
   <ul>
   <p><b><xsl:value-of select="nom"/> : </b></p>
   <li>Distance au soleil: <xsl:value-of select="distance"/><xsl:value-of select="distance/@unit"/></li>
   <li>Masse: <xsl:value-of select="masse"/><xsl:value-of select="masse/@unit"/></li>
   <li>Diamètre: <xsl:value-of select="diametre"/><xsl:value-of select="diametre/@unit"/></li>
   <xsl:if test="satellite>0"><li>Nombre de satellites: <xsl:value-of select="satellite"/></li></xsl:if>
   </ul>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<systeme_solaire>

<etoile>
 <nom>Soleil</nom>
 <type_spectral>G2</type_spectral>
 <age unit="milliard d'annees">5</age>
</etoile>


<planete type="tellurique">
 <nom>Mercure</nom>
 <distance unit="UA">0.4</distance>
 <masse unit="masse terrestre">0.06</masse>
 <diametre unit="diamètre terrestre">0.4</diametre>
</planete>

</systeme_solaire>
```

Could you help me to find why xsl:sort doesn't sort by diameter ?

Comment: You have two templates matching `planete` - that's going to cause more problems than just sorting.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/systeme_solaire">
    <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <title>Les planètes</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="planete[nom!='Terre']">
                <xsl:sort select ="diametre" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="planete" >
    <ul>
        <p><b><xsl:value-of select="nom"/> : </b></p>
        <li>Distance au soleil: <xsl:value-of select="distance"/><xsl:value-of select="distance/@unit"/></li>
        <li>Masse: <xsl:value-of select="masse"/> <xsl:value-of select="masse/@unit"/></li>
        <li>Diamètre: <xsl:value-of select="diametre"/> <xsl:value-of select="diametre/@unit"/></li>
        <xsl:if test="satellite>0"><li>Nombre de satellites: <xsl:value-of select="satellite"/></li></xsl:if>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```